# snap,flatpak, gradio, and apparmor permission problems

Tags: permissions, apparmor

I upgraded to gradio 6.02 which uses snaps.  Now when I try to run gradio
I get the error message

```
cannot create user data directory: /home/xdave/snap/gradio/24: Permission denied
```

dmesg shows the following from apparmor

```
[180455.558983] audit: type=1400 audit(1513542528.411:584): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/snap/core/3604/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" name="/oldmint/home/.ecryptfs/xdave/.Private/ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWZSfo7A7J.06kS1W4QmPVvzrMBrHLcnjlTZXx.Etub7B.WM6ON.8mcBp---/ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWZSfo7A7J.06kS1W4QmPVvzrMBrHLcnjlTZkkrZFZx.j1ADgonKuITq9U--/" pid=723 comm="snap-confine" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1001 ouid=1001
```

The output of  $ ls -al /home/xdave/snap/gradio is

```
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 4 xdave xdave 4096 Dec 15 08:13 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 xdave xdave 4096 Dec 15 08:11 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 xdave xdave 4096 Dec 15 08:13 24
drwxr-xr-x 2 xdave xdave 4096 Dec 15 08:11 common
lrwxrwxrwx 1 xdave xdave    2 Dec 15 08:11 current -> 24
```

I understand that I need to modify a configuration file somewhere to
add the correct permissions, but being new to snaps, and apparmor I could use a little advice so that I can modify the correct file with the correct
command.  I am using an encrypted filesystem with a slightly non standard directory structure that I copied from an older version of UBUNTU a few years ago and can no longer recall the details.  That may be the source of my problem.  Any help will be appreciated.

I switched from snap to flatpak distribution for gradio and the permission problem went away.

Comment: Hello Dave, can you please post the output of `ls -al /home/xdave/snap/gradio`?

Comment: @NerdOfCode 3   I added the output to my question

Comment: Have you tried running `gradio` with `sudo`?

Comment: @NerdOfCode  I get command not found.   $ sudo gradio
[sudo] password for xdave: 
sudo: gradio: command not found

Comment: What is the output of `which gradio`?

Comment: @NerdOfCode OK using instead  sudo `which gradio`  I get
mkdir: cannot create directory '/run/user/0': Permission denied
** Message: gradio-app.vala:188: Gradio 6.0.2 
** Message: gradio-app.vala:196: Locale dir: /snap/gradio/current/usr/share/locale

(gradio:4386): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
 Using the fallback 'C' locale.
No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(gradio:4386): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0

Comment: @NerdOfCode But to answer your question  $ which gradio returns
/snap/bin/gradio

Comment: hm... and `sudo which gradio`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70412/discussion-between-dave-fournier-and-nerdofcode).